# Can angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker be used with bootstrap3?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, accessibility, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to use an accessible date picker in my project. My project uses Bootstrap3, while angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker has bootstrap4 as dependency. Can I use angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker with Bootstrap3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 is a REQUIRED dependency for CSS/Layout as stated here https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker